# Django UpdateView using formset and bootstrap fails

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and I'm trying to write an application that given an activity allows me to save the information of the partecipants (i.e. Person) and how long the partecipation was.

I was able to setup a CreateView, with bootstrap and JavaScript to allow my formset to be dynamic and I'm able to register the activity and the partecipants though the create view.
However, when I try to modify an already existing activity, using an UpdateView, I get several errors.
I tried to reproduce a minimal example of my problem and I got the error "This field is required" that is one of the error I obtain in my main application. I'm trying also to reproduce the second error: the instruction `formset.is_valid()` in *views.py* return `False` since it has an Activity already linked to the Person (violating the `unique_together` rule). This happens everytime: even if I'm just trying to add a second person to the form without changing anything about the first one.

Please, let me know if I missed some files: here's the small example.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Person(models.Model):
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Activity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='ActivityThrough')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('activity-update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class ActivityThrough(models.Model):
    activity = models.ForeignKey(to='Activity', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    person = models.ForeignKey(to='Person', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['person', 'activity']]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Activity, ActivityThrough
from .forms import activity_through_formset, CreateActivityForm
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

# Create your views here.
class UpdateActivity(UpdateView):
    model = Activity
    form_class = CreateActivityForm
    template_name = 'minimal/activities.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UpdateActivity, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['formset'] = activity_through_formset(self.request.POST, instance=context['activity'])
        else:
            context['formset'] = activity_through_formset(instance=context['activity'])

        context['empty_formset'] = activity_through_formset().empty_form
        return context
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form(self.form_class)
        qs = ActivityThrough.objects.filter(activity=self.object)
        formset = activity_through_formset(self.request.POST, queryset=qs)

        if (form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form, formset)
        else:
            for f in formset:
                print(f.errors)
            return self.form_invalid(form, formset)
    
    def form_valid(self, form, formset):
        self.object = form.save()
        formset.instance = self.object
        formset.save()

        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Update was successful')

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
    
    def form_invalid(self, form, formset):
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR, 'Updat cannot be performed')
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, formset=formset))
```

In my **urls.py**

```
path('activity/<int:pk>/', views.UpdateActivity.as_view(), name='activity-update'),
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Person, Activity, ActivityThrough

class CreateActivityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = ['name']
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Name')

class ActivityThroughForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ActivityThrough
        fields = '__all__'
    person = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Person.objects.all(),
        required=True,
        label='Person'
        )
    hours = forms.DecimalField(label='Hours', required=True)

activity_through_formset = forms.inlineformset_factory(
    Activity,
    ActivityThrough,
    fields=['person', 'hours'],
    form=ActivityThroughForm,
    extra=1,
    can_delete=False
)
```

And the template **activities.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <div style="padding: 0 0 1rem">
                <!-- field label -->
                <b>People:</b>
                *
                <!-- end field label -->
                <br>
            
                <!-- field rendering -->
                <div id="formset-template-{{ formset.prefix }}" style="display:none;" generic_id="NNNNN">
                    <div class="form-container">
                        <div class="row form-row spacer">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered formset-table">
                                            {% for hidden in empty_formset.hidden_fields %}
                                                {{ hidden }}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                            <tr>
                                                {% for field in empty_formset.visible_fields  %}
                                                    <th>{{ field.label_tag }}</th>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                {% for field in empty_formset.visible_fields  %}
                                                    <td>{{ field }}</td>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove-form-row mb-4" id="remove-{{ formset.prefix }}-NNNNN">
                                    Remove row
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{ formset.management_form }}
                {% for fs in formset %}
                    <div class="form-container">
                        <div class="row form-row spacer">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered formset-table">
                                            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                                {{ hidden }}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                            <tr>
                                                {% for field in fs.visible_fields  %}
                                                    <th>{{ field.label_tag }}</th>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                {% for field in fs.visible_fields  %}
                                                    <td>{{ field }}</td>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                {% if fs.empty %}
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove-form-row mb-4" id="remove-{{ fs.prefix }}">
                                    Remove row
                                </button>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button id="add-form-{{ formset.prefix }}" class="btn btn-xs float-left btn-success add-form-row">
                        Add row
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="submit-row">
                <input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Update">
            </div>
           
        <script>
            /**
             * Create a new form using a template
             * @param  {HTML} formset_template: the default HTML schema to fill
             * @param  {String} prefix: the Django formset prefix
             * @param  {div} position:
             * @param  {String} generic_id:
             * @return false
             */
            function clone(formset_template, prefix, position, generic_id) {
                // get total forms number in formset
                total = $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
                // build the Regular Expression to replace generic elements
                var prefix_regex = new RegExp('('+prefix+'-'+generic_id+')', 'g')
                // generate new HTML block with "prefix+total indexed" form
                newElement = $(formset_template).html().replace(prefix_regex,
                                                                prefix+'-'+total);
                // place the new form before the "add new" button
                $(position).before(newElement);
                // increase total forms number in formset
                total++;
                $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
                // return false
                return false;
            }

            /**
             * Update the ID indexes of a form input fields
             * @param  {element} parent_div: the element that contains the form
             * @param  {String} prefix: the Django formset prefix
             * @return false
             */
            function reindex_forms(parent_div, prefix){
                // build a Regular Expression to find all "form-INDEX" elements
                var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + ')-(\\d+)','g');
                // get the inner HTML of parent_div
                var parent_html = parent_div.html()
                // find the form in the HTML code
                var target = parent_html.match(id_regex);
                // get the INDEX value (es: form-1 -> 1)
                var splitted = target[0].split('-');
                var index = splitted[splitted.length-1];
                // decrease the index (es: form-1 -> form-0)
                var new_html = parent_html.replace(id_regex,
                                                prefix+'-'+(parseInt(index)-1));
                // update the parent_div HTML code
                parent_div.html(new_html);
                // return false
                return false;
            }

            /**
            * Delete the form and update the ID indexes of successive forms
            * @param  {element} to_remove: the element that contains the "remove" button and the form
            * @param  {String} prefix: the Django formset prefix
            * @param  {String} container_class_div: the class of div that contains the form
            */
            function deleteForm(to_remove, prefix, container_class_div) {
                // calculate the number of total forms in formset
                total = $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
                // retrieve all the forms following the one I'm deleting
                var successive_forms = to_remove.nextAll(container_class_div);
                // reindex each of them
                successive_forms.each(function(){
                    reindex_forms($(this), prefix);
                });
                // remove the form
                to_remove.remove();
                // decrease total number
                total--;
                $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
            }

            // "add new form" event using the generic form template
            $(document).on('click', '.add-form-row', function(e){
                // If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.
                e.preventDefault();
                // get formset prefix
                var formset_prefix = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[2];
                // get formset template
                var formset_template = $('#formset-template-'+formset_prefix);
                // get generic_id attribute
                var generic_id = formset_template.attr('generic_id')
                // get the position of "add new" button
                var position = $(this).parent();
                // clone the template and create a new form in formset
                clone(formset_template, formset_prefix, position, generic_id);
                // return false
                return false;
            });

            // "remove form" event
            $(document).on('click', '.remove-form-row', function(e){
                // If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.
                e.preventDefault();
                // get the CSS class of element that contains form and button
                var container_class = '.form-container';
                // get formset prefix
                var prefix = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
                // get the element to remove (contains the form and the "remove" button)
                var to_remove = $(this).closest(container_class);
                // call deleteForm method
                deleteForm(to_remove, prefix, container_class);
                // return false
                return false;
            });
        </script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```